# how can use cache in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

When i use cache in laravel like this:

```
  return Cache::tags(["product:{$productId}", "user_id:{$userId}"])
    ->rememberForever($key, function () use ($userId, $paginate) {
        return Product::query()
        ->where('user_id', $userId)
        ->paginate(1000)
    });
```

response time is equal without Cache, but when i use toArray after get products like this:

```
 return Cache::tags(["product:{$productId}", "user_id:{$userId}"])
    ->rememberForever($key, function () use ($userId, $paginate) {
        return Product::query()
        ->where('user_id', $userId)
        ->paginate(1000)
        ->toArray()
    });
```

cache is very fast.but I don't want form `toArray()` and i need to collection.

Comment: What do you do and how do you measure? Have you redo test 1 after test2?

Comment: `1000` models I a hell of pagination... You should not return more than `500` at most... you have to have other approach to do what you want, don't paginate `1000` models... PHP is going to take a lot of time to recreate those

Comment: Dri372, i tesed with postman in the defreand senarrios. and toArray for all tests is very faster than collection.

Comment: matiaslauriti : i tested with 100 paginate and not defreand. i think toArray is very faster than get collection.